How to implement an infinite canvas using React Konva?
I'm trying to create an infinite canvas using React and React Konva library to allow users to freely draw and scroll across a seemingly endless workspace. I've looked into various methods but haven't found a clear solution.
Can someone provide a step-by-step guide or example code on how to implement an infinite canvas using React and Konva? I'd appreciate any help or direction to achieve this functionality.

Can't you just create a canvas that extends off screen and when a user scrolls near it's bounds you resize it?

But then when I try to draw shapes they don't appear at the place I tried to draw them, they appear in the initial canvas view that was there

Are you applying offsets to compensate for changes to the position on the canvas after resizing?

No, I'm not applying any offsets or so. I just increased it's width and height.
